# Having trouble in installing pypiwin32 via pip

Tags: python

I am using Raspbian stretch and i am trying to install Pypiwin32 in Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and when i enter the command `pip install pypiwin32` an error showing that:

```
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
Could not find the version that satisfies the requirements pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
```

When i see this error and i download the `pypiwin32` file and enter the command `python setup.py install` it gives an error `No module named _winreg`.
I am using Python2.7.15.
Please help me.

Comment: you could try `import _winreg as winreg`

Comment: Not Worked, any another way.